# dropbox does not sync subfolder anymore?

Tags: dropbox

I noticed one regression(?) recently - I have been using symbolic link in dropbox directory pointing to data directories, something like this - my_dropout_dire/dir1  ====> /path1/data_dir1

There is a directory tree under /path1/data_dir1, whenever there is file update, adding new file or adding new sub directory, I can get auto sync on my other linked computers.

But this stops working recently, since maybe couple weeks back. I have to add a new symbolic link to make it work:

my_dropout_dir/dir1_sub1_sub11  ====> /path1/data_dir1/sub1/sub11

If I do not do this, new files in sub11 is not sync'ed to other computers, and I do not see them on dropbox web repo either.

Does anyone also notice this?

Comment: as of fall 2019 the trick with junction links no more works :(
https://help.dropbox.com/installs-integrations/sync-uploads/symlinks  states: "As of mid-2019, Dropbox no longer follows items outside of your Dropbox account that are linked to by a symlink."

Answer (score 3):

According to Dropbox at this page: https://www.dropbox.com/help/145/en

**Junction points and aliases**

*Dropbox will follow Windows junction points (Windows Vista or later) and sync the files or folders they link to. However, any changes to those files or folders made from the Windows operating system will not sync again until the Dropbox desktop application is restarted. To get around this, move the original folder to your Dropbox and add a junction point from its previous location to link to its new location in the Dropbox folder.*

I had junctions too and they were working fine till some days ago, but apparently they were not supposed to.

Comment: That's so painful. The biggest issue for me is that I forget what is an isn't a junction.. I have taken to leaving text files all over the place. So if I have a folder called "Notes" which is a junction, I will have a text file sibling: "NOTES_IS_A_JUNCTION.txt" with the path to the actual folder.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr I use Dropbox with Windows symbolic links and junctions. While the Dropbox client does NOT detect any file changes during the day, it checks and syncs subfolders and files when it starts up OR  RESUMES.

The files sync under the following conditions:

1. I restart my laptop EVERY morning, and when Dropbox client auto-starts, it syncs up the subfolders and files.
2. If I need to sync files during the day, *I "pause syncing" in the Dropbox client and immediately resume it* - and this syncs up the subfolders/files.

Not the ideal process, but it works.

PS: I've only tried symbolic links with folders on my local machine, not remote machines.

FWIW (as of a few months back) none of the other clients I tried with (Google Drive, Copy) recognized Windows symbolic links and junctions.

Dropbox version: v2.10.52; OS: Windows 8.1